# Surrender or we (will) storm the building

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

> *This is your last chance. Surrender or we (will) storm the building.*

Can this be said without "will", and if so would it be natural?

Comment: Yes, it could be - the present tense for added immediacy.

Comment: Yes, it's a common shortcut. **Do it, or (you will) take the consequences.** **Go now or (you will) face the music.** **Pay up or we take the car back.** And so on.

Comment: It's a matter of set phrases and common idioms. "Stop or I'll shoot!" is one cliched way of expressing this, but "Surrender or die!" is also common. It also depends, as the answer says, on who is speaking (cop or terrorist) and what the precise situation is; you should provide more detail in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This specific example would make sense either way, but it would sound *more* natural to include "will" due to the authoritative tone. Another way of saying this in a natural way would be to conjugate "we" and "will" as "we'll".